# QgsExpression to apply on feature

Tags: qgis, qgis-2.8, expression

I am using QGIS 2.8. For the documentation of QgsExpression I see the evaluate method on feature as deprecated. What am i supposed to use instead of this methods ? I have some expression and need to check if expression evaluate to True or False on given feature.

[image]

Comment: I don't know if that could be applied to your case, but a `QgsExpression` can be used in a `QgsFeatureRequest` in order to call the `.getFeatures()` method of the layer. Like this : ```request = QgsFeatureRequest(QgsExpression("time < 60 AND id_origine = 12"))   
for feature in your_layer.getFeatures(request):   #Do something on the feature... ``` (i can elaborate in an answer if needed)

Comment: No i don't to do this. I had to perform validation check on new feature. So when i create will create a new Feature i want to apply expression and see if it contains some inconsistent data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking at the docs for >= 2.12, not 2.8. That's the correct method to use for the QGIS 2.0 series, but in QGIS 3.0 you'll need to use the method which takes a QgsExpressionContext argument. That's only available in QGIS 2.12 and up.