# QgsExpression.evaluate() is deprecated from PyQGIS?

Tags: python, pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I am developing a plugin for QGIS 2.18 and I am sending queries to a layer:

```
self.userLayer.startEditing()

for feature in self.userLayer.getFeatures():
    value = expression.evaluate(feature)
    feature["ID"] = value
    self.userLayer.updateFeature(feature)

self.userLayer.commitChanges()
```

and I get a *DeprecationWarning*:

```
DeprecationWarning: QgsExpression.evaluate() is deprecated
```

What is the currently preferred way to get an expression evaluated?

Comment: Perhaps the answer to this post might help: [QgsExpression to apply on feature](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/170195/qgsexpression-to-apply-on-feature)